# Lombok does not generate RequiredArgsConstructor and AllArgsConstructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, lombok

I am using Lombok 1.16.18 and Gradle 4.0 with Java 8 and Spring-Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE.

When I build and run the project it succeeds, but when calling services which include Autowiring it fails with NullPointerException using 
`@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))` or `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))`.

I have checked the generated .classes and they are missing the constructors.

Of course if I create the constructors by hand and put `@Autowire` on it it works. But I am working on a big project with a lot of existing code, and don't want to rewrite everything. Any ideas on why this could happen? It looks like gradle or lombok is not preprocessing these annotations, however all the other `@Getter` and `@Setter` etc. are working fine and the generated .class files contain them...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use constructor injection only defining `@RequiredArgsConstructor` with `final` member variables as follows (without using `onConstructor`)

```
@Repository
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FieldRepository {

    private final DSLContext dsl;

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    //... dsl and datasource are correctly injected 

}
```

Comment: And does that make the Autowiring automatic?

Comment: yes, you will have constructor injection because `dsl` and `dataSource` are `final`

Comment: Wow it turns out final is key, I did not know that

Comment: `final` is the key because `@RequiredArgsConstructor` only considers `final ` fields. If you don't have any, Lombok gives you a no-args constructor. Spring will call that, and won't call the additional all-args constructor.